# Update one textbox using javascript function when another changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a javascript function that counts characters in 2 different textboxes and puts the value in a third textbox.

This is the function is as follows:

```
function CountChars() {
             var subjectLength = document.getElementById("txtBoxSubject").value.length;
             var msgLength = document.getElementById("txtBoxMsg").value.length;
             document.getElementById("txtBoxCnt").value = subjectLength + msgLength;
         }
```

I call it from the Message text box using 'onkeyup' and it works fine.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxMsg" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
              TextMode="MultiLine" onkeyup="CountChars()"></asp:TextBox>
```

The Subject textbox can be changed using a dropdown list or a user adding text to it.  So using 'onkeyup' will not work for the Subject textbox.  I tried using 'onchange' and nothing is entered in the Count text box.

This is the Subject html:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxSubject" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="CountChars()"></asp:TextBox>
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I call the javascript function whenver the text changes in the Subject textbox?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
This is the Subject dropdown and the function that is called when it changes.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddListSubject" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="SubjectChanged();">
        </asp:DropDownList>

function SubjectChanged() {
        var strSubject = document.getElementById("ddListSubject").value;
        if (strSubject == "Custom") {
            document.getElementById("txtBoxSubject").value = "";
            document.getElementById("txtBoxSubject").focus();
         }
        else {
            document.getElementById("txtBoxSubject").value = strSubject;
        }
        CountChars(); //number appears for a second then disappears
     }
```

Comment: Can you provide more of the code that you are using? Is the txtBoxSubject onchange firing when you type in the box and blur it? OnChange is only triggered when the element loses focus and the value has changed.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment: Put an onKeyUp handler on txtBoxSubject like you did txtBoxMsg, and an onChange event handler on your dropdown if it changes the value of the textbox.

Comment: I do have an "onkeyup" event handler for the subject textbox because you can add text to the textbox even if you use the dropdown.  The dropdown has an onchange event already and at the end of the java function I call 'CountChars(). The number is in the count textbox for a second then it disappears.  I added the code above.  It looks like it does a Postback but there is nothing in my code-behind that changes the Count text box.

Comment: It is posting back on change. Your autopostback property on the dropdown is triggering it. That's why the value appears and disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dummy me...I removed the AutoPostBack="true" from the Dropdown!
Thanks for all of your help!!

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you not terminating the function with semi column. use something like onkeyup="CountChars();"

Comment: His onKeyUp function is working fine. The issue is he wants an event to fire for the other textbox which can have a value set by user input or by selecting a dropdown value.

Comment: Yes...exactly!  The 'OnChange' event for the Subject dropdown has the CountChars() function at the end.  But the value only is in the textbox for a second.

Comment: Stepping thru the code-behind - the count is present after the Page_Load() method in the Default.asp.cs and after the Page_Load method completes in the Site.Master file, the value is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Your .aspx are using MasterPage? The names of Asp.Net objects changing in the rendered page. Try using <% =% Objeto.ClientID>.

```
function CountChars() {
         var subjectLength = document.getElementById("<%=txtBoxSubject.ClientID %>").value.length;
         var msgLength = document.getElementById("<%= txtBoxMsg.ClientID %>").value.length;
         document.getElementById("<%= txtBoxCnt.ClientID %>").value = subjectLength + msgLength;
     }
```

Or maybe use JQuery. Look at the code below, works as you described.

```
Subject:
<input id="text1" type="text" />
<br />
Msg
<input id="text2" type="text" multiple style="height: 100px" />
<br />
Total: <span id="total">0</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=text]").keyup(function () {
            var total = 0;
            $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
                total += $(this).val().length;
            });
            $("#total").html(total);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I tried both versions and still no luck...The problem is when I use the dropdown to select a Subject.  Then the Count is displayed then goes blank.